# How to set gtk-style and background in GDM3

Tags: gdm, gsettings

I'm triyng to set a different GTk-theme and background for GDM3 (using ubuntu 11.04 and GNOME3 PPA).

As far As I have seen, the GTK-theme used by gdm is exactly the one stored into Gsettings > org.gnome.desktop

So, exactly as I do as another user, I tried executing

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Adwaita
```

from a shell with gdm logged user.

The problem is that it does not change the value of the key into gsettings.

How do I get that gdm can change gsettings keys' values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has something to do with Xauth.... Actually running

```
xhost +SI:localuser:gdm
```

as root (or as admin account) let gdm accept `gsettings set` commands

Actually the solution for setting gtk-theme or background is

1. as root (or admin account) `xhost +SI:localuser:gdm`
2. as root (or admin account) `sudo su gdm -s /bin/bash`
3. as gdm execute in sequence

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme GTK3_THEME`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme ICON_THEME`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme CURSOR_THEME`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file://FILE'`

for example:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:////usr/share/backgrounds/JardinPolar_by_CarmenGloria_Gonzalez.jpg'`

Another important thing to check is that gdm has rw permissions to its home folder, i.e. /var/lib/gdm

**!!!IMPORTANT!!!** 
`exit` to exit from being logged in as `gdm` followed by

`xhost -SI:localuser:gdm` as root or admin user after setting above parameters to deny access to gdm (otherwise it may create problems)

Comment: If you are using GDM3setup, just give xhost+SI:localuser:gdm, use the tool and later xhost -SI:localuser:gdm

Comment: @JuanSebastianTotero: step 3, first line, returns: `** (process:12478): WARNING **: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2: Failed to create file '/var/lib/gdm/.config/dconf/user.GEI68V': Permission denied
`