# Gnome 3 Shell Login, how do I get it?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Gnome 3.2 login theme installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64797/how-to-get-gnome-3-2-login-theme-installed)

I installed Gnome Shell 3.2 and everything is fine other than the fact that I don't get the newly introduced Gnome Shell login prompt and instead get either the standard Ubuntu LightDM or the standard GDM. What do I need to do to get this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/64797/18612

Answer (score 0):

LightDM and GDM are not login prompts, they are login or display managers (DM) that let you select the environment to login to. LightDM happens to be the default one in 11.10. Click the cogwheel to see the available login options or, as you call them, prompts.

Comment: Gnome Shell is selected. What I'm asking for is the actual login prompt isn't themed as Gnome Shell 3.

Comment: @mikewhatever I think the OP is looking for how to configure GDM to look like [this](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.2/figures/gdm.png.en). ([Source](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.2/))

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/76855/18612

Comment: Yep that is what I'm looking for

Comment: Well, sorry folks. My gibberish has become rusty.

Comment: Warrioring64 didn't seem to have any problems understanding what I meant.

Comment: ...and that is why I've only mentioned myself. :~)

Comment: Oh okay, I took that the wrong way (silly internet) :(