# How to change from GDM to LightDM?

Tags: lightdm, gdm

I've upgraded to 12.04. My upgrade didn't go as expected; X crashed at the middle of the upgrade. I had to install many packages manually.

This left me with a GDM login screen.  How do I change from GDM to lightDM?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Let me first tell you that now **Ubuntu** does not use GDM as its display manager in version 12.04...It uses `lightdm` as its display manager...

So the screen you want is actually `lightdm`.

So you will have to install `lightdm` as follows.

Enter these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

[Install lightdm](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lightdm)

---

After installing `lightdm` enter the following commands to set `lightdm` as the default display manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then you will get the following screen:

[image: Display manager explanation]

hit enter and then you will get this screen:

[image: Choose default display manager]

Navigate your option to `lightdm` and hit enter.

Now Restart.

you'll get your screen :)

Comment: This is also the answer for those who upgraded to 17.10 and miss seeing their wallpaper when they select their account.  Lightdm previews the wallpaper, Gdm does not.

Comment: Same goes for 18.04.

Comment: Thanks @Nirmik. It works perfectly.