# Different login background screen?

Tags: login

Its not the regular Ubuntu login screen and this happened just today. Can someone tell me why its different then yesterday? DId i download something accidentally so that it updated itself? More importantly, how can i bring back the regular Ubuntu login screen?

[Different login background screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MG2l.png)

Comment: try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139491/how-to-change-from-gdm-to-lightdm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
Apparently, for some reason, your default dm has been changed to gdm. You need to switch it back to lightdm.

Comment if it worked.