# cannot login in graphic mode - xserver is looping

Tags: login, xserver

I've encountered aproblem in whichi loging in through the graphic interface fails and I go back to the login screen over and over (sheel works fine). It seems to be the same situation as in- [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Both first two answers seems to fail for me. I tried both, and I cant find my xssesions-erros file or remove and reinstall xserver.

I followed instructions from here [How to change from GDM to LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139491/how-to-change-from-gdm-to-lightdm)

But the screens after reconfigure didnt appear.

Comment: What happens when you try to reinstall X?

Comment: @NonnyMoose what is the command do that? i haven't figured it out

Comment: `sudo apt remove xorg && sudo apt install xorg`

Comment: @nonny moose this does seen to affect any thing

Comment: What is the output of that command?