# What's the name of the default Ubuntu login menu?

Tags: login, login-screen

I installed Ubuntu GNOME, then I decided I didn't like it, so I decided the default Ubuntu login menu, need to know what's the name of the login menu so I can install it?

Comment: How can I install the package, then?

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/139491/how-to-change-from-gdm-to-lightdm

Comment: I did it, I'm getting the vanilla LightDM, probably Lubuntu, because I have installed LXDE.