# How to remove GNOME Shell after switching to Unity in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, gnome, package-management

I have decided to remove GNOME and install Unity in my Ubuntu 18.04 and I need some advice on how to do this without affecting my personal files, installed packages and other installed extensions.

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: You can't completely remove Gnome, because Unity depends on it. Also, "Ubuntu x org,waylands,Ubuntu" are not DEs.

Comment: so how can i reduces files for gnome and why do i have those file (Ubuntu x org,waylands,Ubuntu)

Comment: Why remove/replace GNOME? It's almost 99% like Unity. Unity is a dead end.

Comment: its because on  my laptop sometime gnome hangs but unity doesn't that's why i prefer unity over gnome   so you are telling me that  i have to keep them both unity and gnome as the best option

Comment: @christiannshimyumukiza if you're having gnome-shell hangs, it's probably due to a bad GNOME extension. Go [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) and temporarily disable ALL extensions, and see if your problem goes away. Edit your question to show me `ls -al .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back.

Comment: i disabled all the extensions and worked very good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Preliminary*

- It may not be quite worthy to remove the gnome shell desktop. Unity uses many components of Gnome. The space savings may not be that relevant, unless indeed you have a very small hard drive.
- To "granularly" remove all packages only needed by gnome-shell, and not by unity would require a detailed investigation of dependencies. Lacking that, you still can remove gnome-shell. That way, that login option also will be gone, and for practical purposes, the system will already "feel" as if Unity is the only installed desktop.

*Approach*

You could proceed as following. Caveat: do this (as usual) only after you have a full backup of your data. There is always a possibility something goes wrong.

- Remove gnome-shell (this is: only the shell, not the gnome system and core components)

`sudo apt purge gnome-shell`

This will completely remove packages related to the shell. This will also remove the ubuntu-desktop metapackage, because you indeed are removing a core part of the current Ubuntu desktop. This will also remove the gdm login manager.

- Perform an autoremove

`sudo apt autoremove`

This will remove all packages that were automatically installed but are no longer needed by any remaining package.

- Make sure light-dm (automatically installed with `ubuntu-unity-desktop`) is properly set as your default login display manager by running the command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

(see [How to change from GDM to LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139491/how-to-change-from-gdm-to-lightdm) for specifics)

- Check your Unity-desktop core files are all in place by reinstalling the meta-package

`sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-unity-desktop`

Thus, Ubuntu will reinstall the (small) metapackage, and while doing so, check that all required dependencies are (still) in place. May not be needed, but just to be sure.