# Multiple display and performance issues after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, graphics, performance

I have just upgraded to 18.04.

Now once I power the laptop on the login screen is multicoloured. With 16.04 I used to have a section for my password. Now I have to click enter and just enter my password with the screen being multicoloured and cannot see the section where I type my password.

The screen that then appears is blue and black and after a waiting period the Ubuntu logo appears and then I have to wait again before picture is restored and can see Activities and Firefox Web Browser.  Firefox Browser is so slow. At least with 16.04 I could go into history or tools now I have to guess where I have to go. Can someone assist. Thanks

Comment: When an online upgrade fails the best solution is a fresh install. How does it behave in a 18.04 live session?

Answer (score 0):

As ChanganAuto says, it's good to do a fresh install if you're having troubles like this. If that's not an option, or these issues persist, it sounds like you might be having an issue with your desktop manager, since things are not showing up properly in the GUI. Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/139529/1223868) to switch from GNOME desktop manager to the almost-identical but lighter-weight lightdm, which may fix your issues if a clean install is not a working option.