# How do I make GDM use the upstream GNOME theme?

Tags: gnome, gdm, display-manager

I have installed ***GNOME 3.4***

And according to Gnome 3.4,when i reconfigure my display manager to  *GDM*  i should get a login screen like this-

[image]

But when I reconfigure my display manager to *GDM* my screen looks like this-

[image]

Why??

And how can i get the upper one??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gdm&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all), the version of GDM is 3.04.

For 12.04, most, but not all of Gnome 3.4 is available.  Where there were clashes with existing (mostly) canonical supported packages, not all of the gnome 3.4 packages were made available in the repositories.

At the recent UDS, there was some consensus to attempt to get the vast majority of gnome 3.6 into the repositories.  Thus gnome-shell users will get "a better experience".

Until then, you will need to stay with v3.04 GDM unless you use a third-party PPA such as described in the linked question. This will give you a similar login screen.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How to get the GNOME 3 login manager installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64797/how-to-get-gnome-3-2-login-manager-installed/85998#85998)

Comment: thanx a lot!! but but that linked questios answer is for gnome 3.2...will it work for 3.4??

Comment: Tista's PPA has a package for 12.04 - however - I've added an important warning in the issues list for that question.