# Gnome Display Manager

Tags: login, gdm

My gdm login screen looks like this:

[image]

not like:

[image]

How to make it took like the second image?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 . Gdm look similar to 1st image i dont have my screen shot

Comment: This looks like the Gnome 3.2 [login screen](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.2/figures/gdm.png.en).

Comment: can i make gdm to look like 2nd image

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [How to get the GNOME 3 login manager installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64797/how-to-get-the-gnome-3-login-manager-installed). The answer provided covers for 12.04 but it has its own issues. Proceed with caution.

Comment: i had tried that post but i get stuck at login gdm is not loaded . so i had to reconfigure display manager to lightdm.